# Gradle wrapper and daemon

Tags: gradle, gradle-daemon

As many of you already know, the [Gradle daemon](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) can speed considerably Gradle.

I have a multimodule build and using Gradle wrapper.

When running from the command line:

```
gradlew :MyModule:test
```

Gradle spends some seconds analyzing my modules.  If I launch again, it consumes the valuable time again and again.

I'm using Gradle 1.12.

I've tried to set add this line:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

to local.properties, but no luck.

I don't know if I have to change myHome/.gradle/gradle.properties or some other file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.gradle.daemon=true` has to be added to `gradle.properties`, not `local.properties`.